# How to include both CloudWatch group and stream in AWS SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

As part of a SAM template, I would like to create a log group and two log streams.
Initial idea was:

```
myLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: 'myLogGroup'
        RetentionInDays: 180

myLogStream:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogStream'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: 'myLogGroup'
        LogStreamName: 'myLogStream'
```

Unfortunately, when trying to deploy the application I get an error in the event log:

```
12:24:32 UTC+0200   CREATE_COMPLETE     AWS::Logs::LogGroup    myLogGroup   
12:24:31 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::Logs::LogGroup    myLogGroup   Resource creation Initiated
12:24:31 UTC+0200   CREATE_FAILED       AWS::Logs::LogStream   myLogStream    The specified log group does not exist
12:24:31 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::Logs::LogGroup    myLogGroup
12:24:31 UTC+0200   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::Logs::LogStream   myLogStream
```

Is there a way to make AWS wait for the group to be created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Fn::Ref`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) function so that CloudFormation understands the resource is on the same template. Otherwise, when creating the `myLogStream`, CloudFormation thinks it should refer to another (already existing) `myLogGroup`.

```yaml
myLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: 'myLogGroup'
        RetentionInDays: 180

myLogStream:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogStream'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: !Ref myLogGroup
        LogStreamName: 'myLogStream'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution to this issue. Each resource can have a [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute pointing to another resource. For example:

```
myLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: 'myLogGroup'
        RetentionInDays: 180

myLogStream:
    DependsOn: 'myLogGroup'
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogStream'
    Properties:
        LogGroupName: 'myLogGroup'
        LogStreamName: 'myLogStream'
```

This way CloudFormation will wait with creating the stream until the log group is created.